# Why do V8 and Node misformat 2-digit in Date.toLocaleTimeString?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

I want to format the time so that the seconds are displayed differently. However, the javascript method `Date.toLocaleTimeString` does not return the expected result. This has been mentioned several times on Stackoverflow.

**Code:**

```js
let datetimeString = '2022-08-02T16:01:01+02:00';
let dateObj = new Date(datetimeString);
let hourMinuteString = dateObj.toLocaleTimeString('de', {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'});
let secondString = dateObj.toLocaleTimeString('de', {second: '2-digit'});

let tdString = `<time class="time-hour-minute">${hourMinuteString}</time>`;
tdString += `<time class="time-second">:${secondString}</time>`;

console.log(tdString);
```

**Output:**

```html
<time class="time-hour-minute">16:01</time><time class="time-second">:1</time>
```

I know that my desired result can be achieved with `${secondString.padStart(2, '0')}`. But I wonder why this string padding has to be produced manually for JS engines like V8 (Chrome 103.0.5060.134) or Node.js (v18.7.0), when `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions` allows the choice between 2-digit and numeric for the seconds formatting.

I have consulted the [ECMAScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-formatdatetimepattern) for this. As far as I understand it, [section 12.3.2](https://402.ecma-international.org/1.0/#sec-12.3.2) specifies the following rule: If "2-digit" is requested for second, `Intl.NumberFormat` with `{minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping: false}` shall be used for formatting.

I am aware that specifications are disregarded for archaic reasons and any bugs remain unfixed due to possible breaking changes. But I don't understand why this is necessary here: if you really need 2-digit formatting, you solve your problem with padStart. I already looked at the V8 implementation in [js-date-time-format.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/main/src/objects/js-date-time-format.cc#L168), but don't see there why "2-digit" doesn't lead to "ss".

A similar problem was reported as [a bug in 2015](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=507037). A locale issue was suspected behind it, but the problem is now considered fixed.

I'm not familiar with understanding specs correctly - it's quite possible I'm getting it wrong. Can someone enlighten me or is it simply a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug. [crbug.com/v8/13168](https://crbug.com/v8/13168) has been filed.